# ¿Como mostrar la cantidad de solicitudes en 0 si no se han registrado ninguna en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas, la primera es un catalogo de los estatus de una solicitud y la segunda tabla es donde se van registrando dichas solicitudes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo una consulta que me muestra el total de solicitudes que hay y esa ya logre hacerla.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(SR.SolStatus_Id) [No],
    SRS.SolStatus_Descripcion FROM SolicitudResidente SR 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN SolicitudResidenteStatus SRS ON SR.SolStatus_Id = SRS.SolStatus_Id
    GROUP BY SR.SolStatus_Id, SRS.SolStatus_Descripcion;
```

El resultado es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer ahora es otra consulta que me muestre el total de solicitudes del día actual   y si no hay ninguna que me ponga 0 - sin atender, 0 - Rechazada, 0 Aceptadas, tengo la siguiente consulta pero no me arroja nada:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(SR.SolStatus_Id) [No],
SRS.SolStatus_Descripcion FROM SolicitudResidente SR RIGHT OUTER JOIN SolicitudResidenteStatus SRS ON SR.SolStatus_Id = SRS.SolStatus_Id
    WHERE DATEPART(DD, SR.Sol_Fecha) = DATEPART(DD,GETDATE())
    GROUP BY SR.SolStatus_Id, SRS.SolStatus_Descripcion;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que quiero obtener si no hubiera ninguna solicitud registrada en el día seria así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O si hay solo una solicitud del día actual como Aceptada que me arroje lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me haya dado a entender y me pudieran apoyar de favor.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda

Comment: Hola Cook, te aconsejo realizar el [tour] así aprendes como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganar otra medalla. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes hacerlo así:

- Creas una consulta para obtener el total para la fecha indicada agrupado por `SolStatus_Id`.

  ```sql
  SELECT 
      SR.SolStatus_Id,
      COUNT(SR.SolStatus_Id) [Sol_Count]
  FROM SolicitudResidente SR 
  WHERE DATEPART(DD, SR.Sol_Fecha) = DATEPART(DD,GETDATE())
  GROUP BY SR.SolStatus_Id
  ```
- Creas otra consulta donde buscas todos los `SolicitudResidenteStatus` y le "pegas" la consulta anterior, ya sea como una CTE o tabla derivada.
  Ejemplo:

  ```sql
  SELECT 
    SRS.SolStatus_Descripcion,
    COALESCE(T.Sol_Count, 0) [No]
  FROM SolicitudResidenteStatus SRS
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT 
        SR.SolStatus_Id,
        COUNT(SR.SolStatus_Id) [Sol_Count]
      FROM SolicitudResidente SR 
      WHERE DATEPART(DD, SR.Sol_Fecha) = DATEPART(DD,GETDATE())
      GROUP BY SR.SolStatus_Id
    ) T
      ON T.SolStatus_Id = SRS.SolStatus_Id;
  ```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9c652/5)</kbd>

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Marcos, me ha funcionado perfectamente.

Answer (score -1):

En SQL hay una función llamada COALESCE, que si tu consulta encuentra resultados, estos son retornados, caso contrario retorna un valor que definas, por lo general 0.
Una posible solución seria aplicar esta función a tu conteo:

```sql
SELECT
  COALESCE(COUNT(SR.SolStatus_Id), 0) No,
  SRS.SolStatus_Descripcion
FROM
  SolicitudResidente SR
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN SolicitudResidenteStatus SRS ON SR.SolStatus_Id = SRS.SolStatus_Id
WHERE
  DATEPART(DD, SR.Sol_Fecha) = DATEPART(DD, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
  SR.SolStatus_Id,
  SRS.SolStatus_Descripcion;
```

[Acá](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)  esta la documentación oficial por si deseas investigar al respecto.

Comment: Que tal Ernesto, ya intente hacer lo que me comentas pero aun asi no me arroja nada. Que pudiera estar haciendo mal..

Comment: Ejecute el query que me pasaste y sigue sin arrojarme resultados. No encuentro por donde pueda estar el error

Comment: Te agradezco Ernesto por tu atención.